# Move Shapes to specific point by mouse move event and move back when mouse leaves shape

Tags: excel, vba

a few days ago i started with excel and vba. i now reached a point where i want to experiment with shapes and stuff. I created some overly fancy overview page and wanted to make it more fancy for, well just for educating myself. But i cant seem to get any further.

Currently working wiith 5 hexagons. 2 sourrounding 1 big one.

I want the smaller hexagons, which will be behind the big one by default, to move outside by mouseover and move back when the mouse leaves the big hexagon. But currently i only get them to move once. Any suggestions?

EDIT1:I now have it working but it still look .. weird. I dont know how to make the hexagons move more smoothly.

My current code

```
 Private Sub Image1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x        
As Single, ByVal y As Single)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Tests023")
Dim lngCurPos As POINTAPI
Dim MouseIsOver As Boolean
MouseIsOver = True

GetCursorPos lngCurPos
With ws.Shapes("Hexagon 6")
.Left = 50
.Top = 17
End With
With ws.Shapes("Hexagon 7")
.Left = 200
.Top = 100
End With
With ws.Shapes("Hexagon 8")
.Left = 200
.Top = 275
End With
With ws.Shapes("Hexagon 9")
.Left = 50
.Top = 375
End With


Application.Wait (1)

While MouseIsOver = True
GetCursorPos lngCurPos

Select Case lngCurPos.x
Case Is > 450
        MouseIsOver = False

Case Is < 20
        'Function move hexa back in

        MouseIsOver = False


 End Select
 GetCursorPos lngCurPos

'Select Case lngCurPos.y
'Case Is < 400

    'function move hexa back in

   ' MouseIsOver = False
'Case Is > 160
    'function move hexa back in

  '  MouseIsOver = False
'Case Else
   ' MouseIsOver = True
    'End Select

Wend
With ws.Shapes("Hexagon 6")
        .Left = 50
        .Top = 200
        End With
With ws.Shapes("Hexagon 7")
.Left = 50
.Top = 200
End With
With ws.Shapes("Hexagon 8")
.Left = 50
.Top = 200
End With
With ws.Shapes("Hexagon 9")
.Left = 50
.Top = 200
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Comment: Updated with current code

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace application.wait(1) by:

```
t=timer
do
 DoEvents
loop until t-timer>.2 ' this is the waiting time in secods, change at will
```

t is a single var

Comment: Thx for the tip. Is there a big difference depending on wether pausing method i use?

Comment: Well first with wait you have a 1 second resolution, not good for animations, and the last approach will translate to a much smother animation, try this (insert a small cube shape called cube 1) and run this code:
 Sub RotCube()

Dim t1 As Single, t2 As Single
t1 = Timer
Do
 Shapes("cube 1").IncrementRotation (3)
 t2 = Timer
 Do
  DoEvents
 Loop Until Timer - t2 > 0.05
Loop Until Timer - t1 > 10
  
End Sub

Comment: Oh i see. Thx for the example! :) By the way i have managed to complete the task i was on to by my own. Just needed more caffeine! :)